# how to format my returned data by laravel for specific format

Tags: json, laravel-5

```
public function autoComplete(Request $request) {
    $keywords = $request->keywords;
    $phones = [];
    $results = Phone::where('number', 'LIKE', '%' . $keywords . '%')->get();

    if ($results) {
        foreach ($results AS $phone) {
            $phones[] = [
                'id' => $phone->id,
                'text' => $phone->number,
            ];
        }
    }
    return json_encode($phones);
}
```

the previous Method returns the following JSON format

```
[["01111111111"],["01222222222"],["03333333333"],["04444444444"]]
```

But i want it like this

```
{"suggestions":["01111111111", "01222222222", "03333333333", "04444444444"]}
```

I tried to make the return like this

```
return json_encode('suggestions:', $phones);
```

Answer (score 1):

To return that specific format you could use the [map method of collection check this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-map)

so I will give this short solution, here we will change your `foreach`  by `map function`

for that your `autoComplete` function will be like this :

```
public function autoComplete(Request $request) {
    $keywords = $request->keywords;

    $results = Phone::where('number', 'LIKE', '%' . $keywords . '%')->get();

    if ($results) {
        $phones =  $results->map(function($phone) {
            return [
                'id' => $phone->id,
                'text' => $phone->number,
            ];
        });

    }

    return response()->json(['suggestions' => $phones], 201);
}
```

we return `201 http code` to prove that the request has been created with success.

Answer (score 0):

If this method is in a Controller, just return an array, ie:

```
return ['suggestions' => $phones]
```

And Laravel will return it as JSON.